# Gremlin - Update values of multiple edges

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune

I am using AWS Neptune and I have to modify a certain property of a set of EDGEs with specific values. I also need this done in a single transaction. In AWS Neptune, [manual transaction logic using `tx.commit()` and `tx.rollback()` is not supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html). Which means I have to do this operation in a single traversal.

If I was to modify properties of vertices instead of edges, I could have got it done with a query similar to the following one:

```
g.V(<id 1>).property('name', 'Marko').V(<id 2>).property('name', 'Stephen');
```

This is because it is possible to select vertices by id in mid traversal, i.e. the `GraphTraversal` class has `V(String ... vertexIds)` as a member function.

But this is not the same for the case of edges. I am not able to select edges this way because `E(String ... edgeIds)` is not a member function of the `GraphTraversal` class.

Can somebody suggest the correct way I can solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Neptune engine 1.0.1.0.200463.0 added [Support for Gremlin Sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-sessions.html) to enable executing multiple Gremlin traversals in a single transaction.

However, you can do it also with a single query like this:

```
g.E('id1', 'id2', 'id3').coalesce(
    has(id, 'id1').property('name','marko'),
    has(id, 'id2').property('name','stephan'),
    has(id, 'id3').property('name','vadas'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was not aware of Gremlin sessions and I am now glad to read about it. Although, since there are overheads in using sessions, I do not want to proceed with it. The query you have written will work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same result as a mid traversal `E()` using `V().outE().hasId(<list of IDs>)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But in my case, I have to update a property in the edges with different values. In this case, if I get the edges as a list, I can only apply the same transformation to all the edges.

Comment: Understood just wanted to make sure you were aware it is possible to work around the need for E() mid traversal.

Comment: @Kelvin, although it is possible to do it, seems to me it would fail on performance. Doing mid traversal for all V()s is not optimized, let alone running V().outE(). Do you agree?

Comment: It totally depends on the underlying Graph DB Engine implementation as to how things will perform. I personally try to never do V() or E() mid traversal but I know sometimes it can be very convenient to do a V() especially.